# Simultaneous scale and fade out / jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a block of h1 text with the id of "text", and when the "start" button is clicked, I want to simultaneously scale up the h1 text really big and fade it out at the same time.

I would know how to do this if I was using the .animate function, by using "queue: false". But since I am not using .animate, how would I achieve a similar effect?

Here is my code... again, I would like scale and fadeOut to fire at the same time...

```
  $("#start").click(function () {
      $("#text").hide("scale", {percent:3000}, 1000);
      $("#text").fadeOut(1000);
  });
```

Comment: well you can always change the fadeout to animate if everything else fails

Comment: as a side note, you should chain your jquery methods to avoid re-querying the DOM. Or just cache your query in a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my comment you can try something like this, you can choose to cache the jquery object if you want, but if you are only using it once then you don't really need the cacing. I have not tested but I think it will work

```
$( "#start" ).click(function(){
  $( "#text" ).animate( { opacity: "0" }, { queue: false, duration: 1000 }).hide("scale", {percent:3000}, 1000);
});
```

Here is a simple example http://jsfiddle.net/rVNrY/